# How can prevent postback page in the case of using both a JavaScript and a C# method on a button?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, postback

This is an ASP.NET C# question.

```
    <script>
        function buttonfunc() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "js work";
        }
    </script>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <p id="demo"></p>
            <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" Text="Update"
             OnClick="UpdateButton_Click" OnClientClick="buttonfunc()"; return false;/>
        </div>
    </form>

        protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("cs work");
        }
```

In the case of using both a JavaScript and a C# method on a button, how can we stop postback page and display two lines of text at the same time (if possible, without using AJAX)?

Comment: the simple answer is to add an event listener and stop the propagation of the event on form submit.  This is common scenario when adding client-side input validation

Comment: is `"buttonfunc()"; return false;` a typo? did you mean `"buttonfunc();return false;"`? what is the behavior of that after you fixed it?

Comment: I have tried both return false;, but it does not work.

Comment: Also tried add an event listener, but it does not work for me.

Comment: If you want to display "js work" and "cs work" you can't without AJAX. Once you post back to the server anything done via JS will disappear.

Comment: Yes my goal is run both js and C# methods without refresh page when click button, but for some reason don't want to use ajax.

Comment: You really can't do this without AJAX. To fire `UpdateButton_Click` you need to post back to the server. Once you've done that the results of the JavaScript are lost. You could persist the results of the JavaScript to local storage, then use JavaScript when the page reloads as a result of the postback to restore the previous work.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean, I'll think about it.

Answer (score 1):

The way this works is rather handy.

While that button can have both a client side event, and a server side event?

If the client side js code/event returns false, then the server side event will not trigger. This is ideal for say prompting a user to delete a record, or to perform some operation that you require a "confirm" for.

so, take this button:

```
        <asp:Button ID="cmdDel" runat="server" Text="Delete record"
            CssClass="btn"
            OnClick="cmdDel_Click"
            OnClientClick="return DelConfirm()" />

    <script>

        function DelConfirm() {

            return confirm("Really delete this reocrd?")

        }

    </script>
```

so, if the js code (client side) returns true, then server button click runs. If client side js code returns false, then server side button does not run.

You would see this for running above:

[image]

> and display two lines of text at the same time

Hum, that is not clear what you goal here. What 2 lines are you looking to display here?

I mean, either you want/have the server side button event code run, or it does not. As noted, if you return false, then you should not be seeing a post-back. With your sample code, the return false should result in the server side button even NEVER running.

I mean, if you don't do a post-back, then it does not make sense that you can/will have the server side button code run. You require a post-back for this to occur.

Now, you might be able to live with a update panel, and that allows you to define ONLY that part of the web page that will travel up to the server, and run your code. From a user point of view, the page will not appear to have a post back (and you don't actually have a full page post back in this case). The brower scoll bar will not change postion, and you not see the browser "spinner" show a post-back.

So, you drag + drop in the script manager, and then inside of the update paneel, you would have this:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <asp:Button ID="cmdDel" runat="server" Text="Delete record"
                    CssClass="btn"
                    OnClick="cmdDel_Click"
                    OnClientClick="return DelConfirm()" />

                <script>

                    function DelConfirm() {

                        return confirm("Really delete this reocrd?")

                    }

                </script>


            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now, in your code exmaple, place everything inside of the content template, and remove your return false for the client side click. give it a try.

Now, some caution with above. The page life cycle DOES trigger. So, the page load event will fire (like it always does), and then your code stub will run. but to the user, you not see a full page post back. This is often called a "partial page" post-back.

Needless to say, to build a working web forms page, 99% of the time, your page load event that sets up values for controls and does things on the FIRST page load ONLY?

You have the !IsPost back stub in the page load event, so your REAL first time page load code only ever runs one time.

eg:

```
if (!IsPostBack) 
{
     // first time page load
     // load up grid, some combo boxes etc.
     // this code only runs ONE time, on first page load
}
```

Comment: My goal is to keep the js and c# function on the screen.
I tried to remove the returns false; on js and replace return confirm, but still can't avoid refresh the page.

Comment: if you return false, then the code behind event should not run, and you should not see a post-back. This suggests some error(s) in the js code. You can also consider a partial page post-back, and see my edit I just made. Also, you don't' show the element "demo" - what is that?? (sorry I see that now).

Comment: Also, move your js script block to the VERY last line right before the form closing tag.

Comment: Note that UpdatePanels use AJAX behind the scenes.

Comment: yes, they do, but the poster would not have to write any, nor any client side js code, and it works like magic. But, yes, at the end of the day, it does in effect create a ajax block of markup, and only that markup part travels up to the server. While many lament the update panel option, I think they are pure magic. however a update panel does trigger a page life cycle, including the page load even firing. so, it really is better termed what we call a partial page post-back. it still a type of post-back, and still somewhat heaver then a true ajax/web method call.